# Error With JSP search

Tags: html, jsp, search, null

Okay I have a huge problem with this. I have spend hours with my group trying to solve this small problem we have on the group project and cant find the answer

I either get null pointer exeption or something with org.apache.jasper.jasperexception or the most common ones is the try with out catch or finally where I use try and catch .. 
Please help me o

Form for team name

```
<body>
    <h2>Search Team</h2>
    <form action="searchteam.jsp" method="post">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Team Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="tm"/> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

and this here is the searchteam.jsp

```
<%@page import="livescore_pack.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="livescore_pack.Accessor" scope="session"/>

<%
String team = request.getParameter("tm");
Team me = bean.getTeams(team);



if(me == null) 
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
else {
    session.setAttribute("tm", me);
    response.sendRedirect("doSearchTeam.jsp");    
}


%>
```

and the dosearchteam.jsp

```
<%@page import="livescore_pack.Team"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="livescore_pack.Accessor" scope="session"/>


<%
String me = request.getParameter("tm");
Team tm =(Team) session.getAttribute("tm");

 if(me == null)
     response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

    %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="st1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">

        </div>
        <div id="main">
<%

Team team = bean.getTeams(tm.getTm_name()); //dame eshi null





    %>

    <b> <%= tm.getTm_name() %> </b> 
 for <%= tm.getCountry_pk()  %>
 <p> <%= tm.getFounded()%>  </p>
 <p> <%= tm.getStadium() %> </p>
 <p> <%= tm.getManager()%> </p>
 <p> <%= tm.getLeagues() %> </p>
 <p> <%= tm.getCups() %> </p>



<%

}
%>            

        </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

and also the part getTeams in our accessor .java

```
public  Team getTeams(String tm_name) {
    try{
        Connection cn = getGetDATABASE().getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Team WHERE tm_name = ? ";
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, tm_name);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Team tm = new Team();
            tm.setTm_pk(rs.getLong("team_id"));
            tm.setCountry_pk(rs.getLong("country_id"));
            tm.setTm_name(rs.getString("tm_name"));
            tm.setFounded(rs.getLong("founded"));
            tm.setStadium(rs.getString("stadium"));
            tm.setManager(rs.getString("manager"));
            tm.setLeagues(rs.getInt("leagues"));
            tm.setCups(rs.getInt("cups"));

            return tm; 
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        String msg = e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: right now I go to  Connection cn = getGetDATABASE().getConnection(); and get the exemption of not been able to connect or something with naming but usually its this thing never getting the value from the formsString team = request.getParameter("tm");
Team me = bean.getTeams(team);

Comment: in regards to the call to getConnection() failing that sounds like you dont have the database driver in your lib directory (or wherever else you have set up to store your .jar files)

Comment: Amm what do you mean By that? I have connect it to the mysql ip with my username and pass. and then choose the default schema .

Comment: To connect to a mysql database you will need a mysql `JDBC` driver in your classpath, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Being a web project your servlet container should load all .jar files from the wepapps `lib` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay sorry for the delaid answer

I have fixed my problem it seems i was connecting to a wrong part of the database. 
once that was fixed the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your try catch statement has the wrong syntax. it has an extra } before the catch block try deleting that. If that fails and you are still getting errors can you paste in a copy of the jasper exception that is returned

Also as far as i can see you are calling getTeams() twice with the same name. Once in searchteam.jsp and the second time in dosearchteams.jsp. You have set all the variables in serachteam.jsp you do not need to call it again in dosearchteams.jsp this appears to be a redundant call.

Comment: indenting is terrible, that extra `}` is for the while loop

Comment: You're right of course.. Can't believe I missed that